# How to remove junk character from the input string in Datastage

Tags: db2, datastage

I am using Datastage 11.5

Conside the input string 'This is  � Test'.

I want to avoid such data to be inserted or get the value replaced with ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [convert function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-convert-function). You can list a number of characters and a replacement character or string. The only problem is to identify all characters you want to get rid of.